# After jquery function position responsive is over

Tags: jquery

I have this script. When the function runs, relative is not working. How can I fix this, problem?

```
$(".arrow_right").click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".arrow_right").hide();
  },100);

  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".arrow_left").show();
  },100);

  $(".comment_panel").stop().fadeOut(100);
  $(".film_area").animate({"margin-left":"+=160px"},200);
  $(".arrow_right").animate({"right":"0px"},200);
});
```

Comment: Please fix your code-indentation and your grammar.

Comment: When you mean "relative" you're talking about the setTimeout-Stuff? Have you looked into the API docs of jQuery already? Since version 1.4, there is a chainable .delay() function. http://api.jquery.com/delay/